# 3D chess game without logic

Tags: windows, 3d, chess

I am looking for a 3D chess game which I can freely manipulate. It is best defined by excluding features a normal chess game has

It must

- NOT have a KI that performs moves
- NOT check for correctness of moves (e.g. horse must go 2+1)
- NOT check for mate positions
- NOT limit the number of characters on the board
- NOT perform statistics

I want

- to position all characters freely (one character per cell, not *anywhere*)
- to add characters whenever I like
- to add invalid characters (e.g. 5 kings)
- a totally reduced UI, just a chess board, nothing else
- a nice 3D view with shadows. Should not look too ugly.
- Windows (7+) support
- it to be gratis or cheap (less than 20 USD)

It needn't

- be able to rotate the view

Something like this would be ok:

[image: Chess example]

I think you got it.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you may be interested in software called "Tabletop Simulator".  This will allow you to create a (or download someone else's) chess board. Here are the features that you're interested in:

- You can do anything you want to the pieces and the board
- Doesn't check for any moves (doesn't process anything you do)
- Pretty awesome UI - I believe you can hide/remove backgrounds

It's available on steam with some very positive reviews,

## [Tabletop Simulator](http://store.steampowered.com/app/286160/) ($19.99*)

- At the time of this writing

> Create your own original games, import custom assets, automate games with scripting, set up complete RPG dungeons, manipulate the physics, create hinges & joints, and of course flip the table when you are losing the game. All with an easy to use system integrated with Steam Workshop. You can do anything you want in Tabletop Simulator. The possibilities are endless!
>
> [image: Chess board screenshot]
>
> [image: Chess board animation]

Comment: One of the images is broken

Comment: @ThomasWeller Whoops, my mistake - I've uploaded it to Imgur so it should stay there for good.